# Error in R script when run on a cluster. Script works fine on laptop

Tags: r, function

So I am not sure why this is happening and I have tried different versions of R to see if there was an error with that version. I am having an issue with one of my functions.

```
replacement<-function(x){
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/3'),0)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/3'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='2/3'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='3/3'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='./.'),0) 
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/0'),0)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/1'), 1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/2'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/1'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='2/2'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/2'),0)
}
```

I think there shouldn't be any issues with this function. Seems rather straight forward. My script requires a bit more memory than I have on my laptop so I am running it on my university's cluster (version 3.5.0). When I attempt to run this function on my data, it starts to bug out. I made a smaller data set to see what the issue was and this is what is happening. I have no idea why my function get all messed up? Does anyone have any idea what is going on??

```
> replacement<-function(x){
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='0/3'),0)
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='1/3'),1)
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='2/3'),1)
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='3/3'),2)
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='./.'),0) 
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='0/0'),0)
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='0/1'), 1)
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='1/
+   x=replace(x,
+   x=replace(x,
+   x=replace(x,which(x=='
+ }
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"  x=replace(x,which(x=='
}"
```

I have tried this on version 3.4.2 as well and have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what error you were getting, as I was able to run your function without any errors. You can simplify your code quite a bit by combining the logical tests that have the same assignment value:

```
x1 <- c('0/3' , '1/3' , '2/3' , '3/3' , './.' , '0/0' , '0/1' , '1/2' , '1/1' , '2/2' , '0/2')

replacement<-function(x){
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/3'),0)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/3'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='2/3'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='3/3'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='./.'),0) 
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/0'),0)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/1'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/2'),1)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='1/1'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='2/2'),2)
  x=replace(x,which(x=='0/2'),0)
  x
}

replacement_2<-function(x){
  x[x %in% c('0/3', './.', '0/0', '0/2')] <- 0
  x[x %in% c('1/3', '2/3', '0/1', '1/2')] <- 1
  x[x %in% c('3/3', '1/1', '2/2'       )] <- 2
  x
}

replacement(x1) 
# [1] "0" "1" "1" "2" "0" "0" "1" "1" "2" "2" "0"
replacement_2(x1)
# [1] "0" "1" "1" "2" "0" "0" "1" "1" "2" "2" "0"
```